# Find array item with matching object by key and value in PHP

Tags: php, json

I haven't found the answer on Stack Overflow.

This is an extract of JSON send by the API Foursquare:

```
{ popular: {
    isOpen: false,
    isLocalHoliday: false,
    timeframes: [{
            days: "Aujourd'hui",
            includesToday: true,
            open: [{
                renderedTime: "18:00–02:00"
            }],
            segments: []
        },
        {
            days: "sam.",
            open: [{
                renderedTime: "18:00–02:00"
            }],
            segments: []
        },
        {
            days: "dim.",
            open: [{
                renderedTime: "18:00–21:00"
            }],
            segments: []
        },
        {
            days: "lun.",
            open: [{
                renderedTime: "19:00–Minuit"
            }],
            segments: []
        },
        {
            days: "mar.",
            open: [{
                renderedTime: "18:00–Minuit"
            }],
            segments: []
        },
        {
            days: "mer.",
            open: [{
                renderedTime: "18:00–23:00"
            }],
            segments: []
        },
        {
            days: "jeu.",
            open: [{
                renderedTime: "18:00–Minuit"
            }],
            segments: []
        }
    ]
},
```

The order of the objects in the `timeframes` array is not consistent between responses from the Foursquare API (the array may start at Monday, or Tuesday, etc, depends on the current day I believe).

I would like to get the `.open[0].renderedTime` value of the Monday (where `days` is `"lun."`).

How can I do find the `timeframes` entry that has `days` equal to Monday?

I would like to have something like :

```
$data = $parsedJSON->response->venue;
echo $data->response->venue->popular->timeframes->
  lun /* doesn't work */
  ->open[0]->renderedTime;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: That's not valid JSON to test with.  Decode as an array and do a `print_r()`.

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php